# How can I connect to a LAN server to play Counter Strike: Global Offensive?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I am on a wireless network trying to play CS go with my friends. They all are in the same room with me. How can I create a server so I can play with my friends? In CS 1.6 we launch a hlds file which is in the cs 1.6 directory. We create a server through launching this hlds file. But in Counter Strike: Global Offensive I can't find hlds file, so now I don't know how to setup or create a server.

Answer (score 3):

Valve keeps the documentation for installing CS:GO servers on the [Valve Developer Wiki](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Dedicated_Servers).  The docs don't present a direct step-by-step procedure, though, so I'll try to assist.

1. Download [SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD) (look for the "Windows zip file" link)
2. Unzip SteamCMD into a folder on your computer.
3. Double click steamcmd.exe
4. Wait while steamcmd gets the latest patches
5. At the `Steam>` prompt, type `login anonymous` to get connected to Steam
6. At the `Steam>` prompt, type `force_install_dir cs_go` to set the directory where CS:GO will be installed to.  In this case, it's the folder cs_go in the SteamCMD folder
7. At the `Steam>` prompt, type `app_update 740 validate` to initiate the dedicated server download.
8. Wait for the files to download (the time depends on Steam server load and your internet connection)

Once the download is complete, you can close SteamCMD.

To launch the server:

1. Open a command prompt (On Win7, you can open the Windows menu and type cmd.exe)
2. Get to the directory where you installed the dedicated server (ie, `cd C:\Users\YOUR USERNAME\Downloads\steamcmd_win32\cs_go`)
3. Launch the server exe with a command like: `srcds -game csgo -console -usercon +game_type 0 +game_mode 0 +mapgroup mg_bomb +map de_dust`

The actual server options will vary depending on what type of CS:GO game server you want to run.  More examples are [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive_Dedicated_Servers) and complete srcds docs are [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Command_Line_Options#Source_Games).

Running the server consumes some resources, so if you've got a PC that won't be playing the game, you can use that to run the server.  If your PC is powerful enough, you might be able to run both the server and the game on the same machine.  However, that will depend on a number of factors that are specific to your setup.

Comment: thanku for ur  answer. i am doing all the things you have mentioned .. but i didnt get the point 6. as i paste this command "force_install_dir cs_go" ..it has done nothing i mean again steam> comes up then i paste this command app_install 740 validate then message comes up says this ">>> command not found:app_install"

Comment: agent86 i have game cs global offensive is installed in this directory C:\Program Files\Counter-Strike Global Offensive            and SteamCMD is extracted  in here  E:\Steam

Comment: @user49842, apologies, I had a mistake in my steps.  the command is `app_update` and not `app_install` - try again and it should work better this time :)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding the -ip command line parameter with the LAN ip of the server? 
If you activated the gamemodes_server, are you sure it does not have any syntax error in there?

I've been setting up csgo servers since May 2013 and those were the most common issues.